# @Autowired not working in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, autowired, spring-restcontroller

I am working on spring-boot application. In that application `@Autowired` is not working for some classes.

I have below classes in spring boot application:

```
@Component
public class SessionUser {
    private static final String SESSION_PRINCIPAL = "session.principal";

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    //more code
}


@RestController
public class RefreshUserPermissionsRequestHandler {
    @Autowired
    TaskTrigger taskTrigger;

    @Autowired
    private SessionUser sessionUser;

}

public class LocalFileUserProviderImpl {
    @Autowired
    private SessionUser sessionUser;

    //more code 
}
```

In `RefreshUserPermissionsRequestHandler`, the `SessionUser` bean is injecting properly, but in `LocalFileUserProviderImpl` it's not working. Even I tried to annotate `LocalFileUserProviderImpl` with `@RestController` and `@Controller` but both are not working.

Can anyone help me what is going wrong here? Please let me know if any further info is required.

Comment: Can you annotate your classes as @Component so they are detected by Spring?

Comment: Judging from the lack of a `@Component` annotation on `LocalFileUserProviderImpl` I suspect you are doing `new LocalFileUserProviderImpl()` yourself and expect Spring to somehow magically know that instance and inject it. That is not going to happen.

Comment: Thanks @ M. Deinum I missed basic rule of spring :). It helped